# testing a program in bash

Tags: bash

I wrote a program in c++ and now I have a binary. I have also generated a bunch of tests for testing. Now I want to automate the process of testing with bash. I want to save three things in one execution of my binary:

1. execution time
2. exit code
3. output of the program

Right now I am stack up with a script that only tests that binary does its job and returns 0 and doesn't save any information that I mentioned above. My script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: testScript <binary> <dir_with_tests>"
    exit 1
fi

binary="$1"
testsDir="$2"

for test in $(find $testsDir -name '*.txt'); do
    testname=$(basename $test)

    encodedTmp=$(mktemp /tmp/encoded_$testname)
    decodedTmp=$(mktemp /tmp/decoded_$testname)

    printf 'testing on %s...\n' "$testname"

    if ! "$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp > /dev/null; then
        echo 'encoder failed'
        rm "$encodedTmp"
        rm "$decodedTmp"
        continue
    fi

    if ! "$binary" -u -f $encodedTmp -o $decodedTmp > /dev/null; then
        echo 'decoder failed'
        rm "$encodedTmp"
        rm "$decodedTmp"
        continue
    fi

    if ! diff "$test" "$decodedTmp" > /dev/null ; then
        echo "result differs with input"
    else
        echo "$testname passed"
    fi

    rm "$encodedTmp"
    rm "$decodedTmp"
done
```

I want save output of `$binary` in a variable and not send it into `/dev/null`. I also want to save time using `time` bash function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for the output to be saved in a shell variable, I tried answering this without using output redirection – which saves output in (temporary) text files (which then have to be cleaned).

### Saving the command output

You can replace this line

```
if ! "$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp > /dev/null; then
```

with

```
if ! output=$("$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp); then
```

Using command substitution saves the program output of `$binary` in the shell variable. Command substitution (combined with shell variable assignment) also allows exit codes of programs to be passed up to the calling shell so the conditional `if` statement will continue to check if `$binary` executed without error.

You can view the program output by running `echo "$output"`.

### Saving the time

Without a more sophisticated form of Inter-Process Communication, there’s no way for a shell that’s a sub-process of another shell to change the variables or the environment of its parent process so the only way that I could save both the time and the program output was to combine them in the one variable:

```
if ! time-output=$(time "$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp) 2>&1); then
```

Since `time` prints its profiling information to `stderr`, I use the parentheses operator to run the command in subshell whose `stderr` can be redirected to `stdout`. The programming output and the output of time can be viewed by running `echo "$time-output"` which should return something similar to:

```
<program output>
<blank line>
real    0m0.041s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s
```

Comment: Thx, that is almost exactly what I wanted. It would be even better if I could have output of the program and time info in separate files/variables. But anyway, I can handle it like this.

Comment: @Anton A while back, I spent a long time trying to do something similar but couldn't figure out any other way to do it without creating temporary files. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the process status in bash by using `$?` and print it out by `echo $?`.
And to catch the output of time, you could use sth like that

```
{ time sleep 1 ; } 2> time.txt
```

Or you can save the output of the program and execution time at once

```
(time ls) > out.file 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save output to a file using output redirection. Just change first `/dev/null` line:

```
if ! "$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp > /dev/null; then
```

to

```
if ! "$binary" -c -f $test -o $encodedTmp > prog_output; then
```

then change second and third /dev/null lines respectively:

```
if ! "$binary" -u -f $encodedTmp -o $decodedTmp >> prog_output; then

if ! diff "$test" "$decodedTmp" >> prog_output; then
```

To measure program execution put

`start=$(date +%s)`

on the first line

then

```
end=$(date +%s)
echo "Execution time in seconds: " $((end-start)) >> prog_output
```

on the end.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `time` command to measure execution duration.

Comment: **time** utility is to summarize system resource usage.